# Exact evaluation of sign of floating point expression

Tags: geometry, floating-point

I'm trying to determine whether a line (defined by two points) and a circle (defined by three points) intersect. The points use doubles.

In [this](https://www.geometrictools.com/Documentation/IntersectionLine2Circle2.pdf) document the following discriminant is given (formula 6):
$\delta=(D\cdot\Delta)^2-|D|^2(|\Delta|^2-R^2)$. When $\delta>0$ there are 2 intersection points, if $\delta=0$ there is 1 intersection point and when $\delta<0$ there are none.

How can I determine the sign of $\delta$ *exactly*?
I'm currently using infinite precision arithmetics, but these calculations are extremely expensive. Is there a way to do it just in floating point?

As an alternative, would it be possible to set an error bound on the calculation and if $|\delta|<\epsilon$ for some (large) $\epsilon$ do the calculation again using infinite precision arithmetics.

I expect that in 90% of the cases the floating point answer will be just fine, so I expect this would speed up the algorithm vastly. I'm just unsure I can set a bound on the final result while there are many calculations up front, as well as how do I determine the right value for $\epsilon$?

Comment: This may help: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_arithmetic

Comment: In the first place, do you have a good reasons to require an exact evaluation ? If the data themselves are noisy (or suffer truncation errors), the outcome can be wrong anyway. And if you find two intersections with a nearly zero discriminant, will their evaluation make sense ?

IMO, more context is required.

Comment: @YvesDaoust The algorithm that uses this information (point in polygon check) can fail miserably for edge-cases when the sign is not determined exactly. I'm not trying to actually find the intersections, which is why I'm only interested in the sign if the discriminant.

Comment: @RemcoPoelstra: do you mean *thick* point-in-polygon ?

Comment: See also https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/27777/accurate-evaluation-of-the-sign-of-a-polynomial

Comment: @YvesDaoust, no, just a floating-point point and a polygon consisting of straight and curved line segments (all in floating point).

Comment: @lhf Seems this covers my needs very well indeed. It's a bit a difficult read for me, but I'll work my way through it.

Comment: For point-in-polygon, you normally have the choice of the direction of the line. Taking it axis-parallel simplifies the computation.

Comment: If you work with the endpoints of the edges (segments or arcs), and assign a positive or non-positive sign to each wrt the line, a bulletproof method is to report for every edge a number of intersections having a parity compatible with the signs of endpoints. This relieves the need to care about accuracy. (If the parity that you find does not match, you can sacrifice the most dubious intersection.)

Comment: Why the use of this specific calculation when you have a circle (I assume known equation in  2D) and a line (straight in same plan)?

Comment: @YvesDaoust I'm afraid that method does not account for the case where the test point is 'inside' the arc, with both end points to the left or right (assuming a vertical ray). Or am I missing something?

Comment: @Moti There is no specific reason I choose this calculation other than that it seemed to fit nicely with my definition of the line and circle and that the document was well written and comprehensible. You believe there is an easier discriminant?

Comment: The floating point error bound from this computation is somewhere around $10\mu\,|D|^2(|Δ|^2+R^2)$ where $\mu$ is the machine constant or working relative accuracy of the floating point type. With that you can implement your selective refinement strategy.

Comment: @RemcoPoelstra: yes you are missing something. Stick to exact computation.

Comment: @Remco Solve the two equations with two unknowns - you will get a term that will imply the three cases - 2, 1 or no solutions in real terms (I assume you are not looking for complex solutions). If this computation requires a very low computation error I wonder what type of "input" you have to the process.

Comment: @Moti The discriminant given above is already the square root term of the solution. The high accuracy is needed because computational geometric problems can be very ill defined, even if the input is 'nice'.

Comment: I am just wondering if the reason for your trouble is that the discriminant provides "too much information" - what is the meaning of $\delta$ large or small?